# Is there a way around the content blocking of link shortners?

Tags: support, short-links

I hate link shortners as much as everyone else here, but sometimes a question is actually *about* link shortners. What should we do in that case?

I just tried editing a question to make it a bit easier to read, but my edit was rejected because it was about a link shortner. Here's my failed edit:

[image]

Comment: Your question isn't about url shorteners, it's about a regex to parse URLs in JavaScript. Focus on that; it really doesn't matter what the beginning part of the URL is in your example.

Comment: It isn't my question: it's an existing question I was editing for readability.

Comment: Does that mean you can't change the example to one that isn't blocked without changing the intent of the question? `http://super.ads/12345/http://mydomain.com`

Comment: Link to the question.  I'm pretty sure you can just put tick marks around the blocked URL.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598068/replace-href-part-using-regexp

Comment: Ugh.  What a mess.  Changed them all to `url.sh`